# Trying to add two data sources/types to a SelectableButton in RecycleView

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

Sorry if this is a ridiculous question. I'm new to programming and so far I've been able to lurk my way through problems that have already been answered, but I can't find anything that answers this particular issue, so here I am with my first ever question to the Stack community. Yay!

I'm writing a fresh produce stock management app in Python/Kivy, using an SQLite database. I've got a RecycleView list with SelectableButton viewclass, and have it contained within a GridLayout.

I have a class method (`getItems`) within `ItemList` that extracts the item(string) and quantity(real) from the database, and adds it to a `ListProperty` variable (`data_all`), which is where the `SelectableButton` should in turn get its labels from.

In my example, I've commented out this method, and populated the list in the format that the `getItems` should do. Actually, as I write this, I wonder if there is a critical difference between the way SQLite stores REAL values, and how python stores float values.

Anyway, ultimately, I'm having trouble displaying the item next to it's quantity in the Recycle view list.

The closest I've come to having it work is to make a 2-column `GridLayout`, with the item name on the left as a Button, and the quantity on the right as a Label. However, when the list exceeds the bottom of the screen, they scroll independently of one another, as per example 1 below. This is not what I want as the items and quanitities should be next to one another.

Python:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout   import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, DictProperty
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import string

#import sqlite3

class EditItemPopup(Popup):
    obj = ObjectProperty(None)
    obj_text = StringProperty("")

#The full code also includes quantity data to be displayed here, but that's irrelevant to the question

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(EditItemPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = obj
        self.obj_text = self.obj.text

class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''

class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index

        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected

    def on_press(self):
        popup = EditItemPopup(self)
        popup.open()

    def update_changes(self, txt):
        self.text = txt


class ItemList(Widget):
    '''User selects, adds, edits, and deletes items and quanitities'''

    #this is how the data is extracted from the SQLite db
    data_all = ListProperty(['Apples', 3.0, 'Bananas', 12.0, 'Lettuce', 16.5, 'Asparagus', 3.0])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ItemList, self).__init__(**kwargs)
#       self.getItems()
        return

#This method, and the invocation for it in the __init__ methd is how I would typically pull data from the SQLite db. I've left it commented here and open to constructive criticism
#   def getItems(self):
#       c.execute("SELECT item, quantity FROM itemTable ORDER BY item ASC")
#       rows = c.fetchall()
#       for row in rows:
#           for col in row:
#               self.data_all.append(col)

class ColStock(App):
    def build(self):
        return ItemList()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ColStock().run()
```

Kivy:

```
<EditItemPopup>:
    title: "Edit Item"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 500
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            cols: 3
            Label:
                text: root.obj_text

        Button:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            text: "OK, thanks"
            on_press: root.dismiss()

<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected==True else (0, 0, 0, 0)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<ItemList>:
    GridLayout:
        size: root.width,root.height
        cols: 2
        RecycleView:
            viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
            data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_all[0::2]]
            SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                default_size: None, dp(30)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None

                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                multiselect: True
                touch_multiselect: True

        RecycleView:
            viewclass: 'Label'
            data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_all[1::2]]
            RecycleGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                default_size: None, dp(30)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
```

I tried working around this by instead creating one GridLayout column, with the item name, a string seperater, and quantity all on the same button, and an `rpartition("......qty: ')` in the `EditItemPopup` init method to extract only the item name.

However, everything I've tried returns an error, usually a TypeError.

Python:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout   import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, DictProperty
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import string

#import sqlite3

class EditItemPopup(Popup):
    obj = ObjectProperty(None)
    obj_text = StringProperty("")
    item_name = StringProperty("")
    item_qty = StringProperty("")

#The full code also includes quantity data to be displayed here, but that's irrelevant to the question
    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(EditItemPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = obj
        self.obj_text = self.obj.text
        self.item_tuple = self.obj_text.rpartition("......qty: ")
        self.item_name = self.item_tuple[0]
        self.item_qty = self.item_tuple[2]


class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index

        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected

    def on_press(self):
        popup = EditItemPopup(self)
        popup.open()

    def update_changes(self, txt):
        self.text = txt


class ItemList(Widget):
    '''User selects, adds, edits, and deletes items and quanitities'''

    #this is how the data is extracted from the SQLite db
    data_all = ListProperty(['Apples', 3.0, 'Bananas', 12.0, 'Lettuce', 16.5, 'Asparagus', 3.0])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ItemList, self).__init__(**kwargs)
#       self.getItems()
        return

#This method, and the invocation for it in the __init__ methd is how I would typically pull data from the SQLite db. I've left it commented here and open to constructive criticism

#   def getItems(self):
#       c.execute("SELECT item, quantity FROM itemTable ORDER BY item ASC")
#       rows = c.fetchall()
#       for row in rows:
#           for col in row:
#               self.data_all.append(col)

class ColStock(App):
    def build(self):
        return ItemList()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ColStock().run()
```

Kivy:

```
<EditItemPopup>:
    title: "Edit Item"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 500
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            cols: 3
            Label:
                text: root.item_name
            Label:
                text: root.item_qty

        Button:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            text: "OK, thanks"
            on_press: root.dismiss()

<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected==True else (0, 0, 0, 0)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<ItemList>:
    GridLayout:
        size: root.width,root.height
        cols: 1
        RecycleView:
            viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
#added self.obj_text.rpartition("......qty: ") for the popup window to extract item name as string
            data: [{'text': str(x) + "......qty: " + "Quantity goes here"} for x in root.data_all[0::2]]
            SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                default_size: None, dp(30)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None

                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                multiselect: True
                touch_multiselect: True
```

I've probably violated every convention in programming, and I know it's a hack, but I'd be happy with anything that works. Thank you in advance to anyone who can shed some light on this. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I've been stuck on this for about 2 or 3 weeks, and the day I ask for help on S.E is the day I discover a solution through trial and error that works for my needs.

I can use the following syntax in the kivy file which adds both item and quantity to each SelectableButton by iterating each pair in the `data_all` list:

```
data: [{'text': str(x) + "......qty: " + str(y)} for x,y in zip(root.data_all[0::2],root.data_all[1::2])]
```

I then add the following to the Popup's **init** method (python file) to extract only the item name for the label:

```
self.obj_tuple = self.obj_text.rpartition("......qty: ")
self.item_name = self.obj_tuple[0]
```

The `self.item_name` can then also be used to reference the correct row in the SQLite db.

Other suggestions are welcome of course, but I hope this helps someone who is facing similar issues.